# What "fields" Scamander here referring to?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

> Scamander: I've just completed a year in **the fields**.
> I'm writing a book about magical creatures.

What "fields" Scamander here referring to ?

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/in-the-field/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He doesn't say "*in the fields*", he says "*in the field*", according to the [official script book](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them:_The_Original_Screenplay).

> **NEWT:** *I’ve just completed a year **in the field**. I’m writing a book about magical creatures.*

Per Dictionary.com...

> When someone’s *in the field*, they’re “in direct contact with a source of
> data or subject of interest,” as in doing work outside an office or
> laboratory.
>
> <sub><sup>[WHAT DOES IN THE FIELD MEAN?](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/in-the-field/)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

"In the field" is a common expression among biologists, anthropologists, archaelogists, etc., meaning that they've gotten out of their labs, classrooms, libraries, and offices, to pursue their researches in the real world.  An archaeologist would go on a dig, an anthropologist might spend six months or a year living in a village with Amazonian natives, a linguist might spend a similar time in a region where his language of study (Basque, say, or Punjabi, perhaps) is spoken natively as the primary language -- and someone like Newt Scamander had spent a year actually finding, cataloging, and in a few cases capturing fantastic beasts (he had, in fact, a number of them in his valise!).